# Passing input value with array name in onchange to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays

I have search everywhere and learn that input tag can have an array name attribute like writing name="mark_delete[ ]" as array PHP post by form. But what I'm struggling of is the javascript part (I only use simple javascript anyway) to work.

I have 3 input name: prize[ ], quantity[ ], total[ ];

I want the total get the prize times the quantity.

- The prize is fixed
- The quantity is where the user's input
- The total is read only.

Using onchange in input tag with array name

The 2 code show below work successfully in PHP:

Sample code 1 (using foreach): *You may skip this code

```
<?php
    //delete_account.php

    session_start();

    if (isset($_SESSION['login_user'])) {
        include("dbconn.php");

        if (isset($_POST['delete']) && $_POST['mark_delete'] > 0) {
            $mark_delete = $_POST['mark_delete'];

            foreach ($mark_delete as $x) {
                $sql = "UPDATE account SET status = 0 WHERE id_number = '$x'"; //status change to 0 as inactive instead of deleting the row data
                mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            }
        }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Delete Account</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Restaurant Management Information System</h1>
        <h3>Mark the accounts that you want to delete and press the delete button...</h3>
        <div>
            <a href="order.php"><button>Menu</button></a>
            <a href="items.php"><button>Add New Item</button></a>
            <a href="log.php"><button>View Activity Log</button></a>
            <a href="home.php"><button>Logout</button></a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <form action="delete_account.php" method="post">
            <?php
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM account ORDER BY last_name, first_name";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

                if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                    echo "<ol>";
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                        if ($row['status'] == 1) { //display account with status value of 1 as active
                            echo "<li>";
                            echo "<input type='checkbox' name='mark_delete[]' value='" . $row['id_number'] . "' />";
                            echo $row['last_name'] . ", " . $row['first_name'] . "</li>";
                        }
                    }
                    echo "</ol>";
                }
                else
                    echo "No account existed...";
            ?>
                <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
<?php
    }
    else {
        header("Location: home.php");
        exit();
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Sample code 2 (using while / mysqli_fetch_assoc()): *You may skip this code

```
<?php
    //items.php

    session_start();

    if (isset($_SESSION['login_user'])) {
        include("dbconn.php");

        if (isset($_POST['add_stocks'])) {
            $amount_add = $_POST['amount_add'];
            $sql = "SELECT item_id, stock FROM items";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

            if (!empty($amount_add)) {
                $x = 0;
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                    if (is_int((int)$amount_add[$x])) {
                        $stock = $row['stock'] + $amount_add[$x];
                        $sql = "UPDATE items SET stock = '$stock' WHERE item_id = '$row[item_id]'";
                        mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                    }
                    $x++;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (isset($_POST['add_new'])) {
            $stock = $_POST['stock'];
            if (empty($stock))
                $stock = 0;
            if (is_int((int)$stock)) {
                $sql = "INSERT INTO items (item_name, prize, stock) VALUES ('$_POST[item_name]', '$_POST[prize]', '$stock')";
                mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            }
        }
        else if (isset($_POST['item_delete'])) {
            $item_delete = $_POST['item_delete'];

            $x = 0;
            while (!isset($item_delete[$x]))
                $x++;
            $sql = "DELETE FROM items WHERE item_id = '$item_delete[$x]'";
            mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Add Items</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Restaurant Management Information System</h1>
        <h3>Restock some items or add a new one...</h3>
        <div>
            <a href="order.php"><button>Menu</button></a>
            <a href="log.php"><button>View Activity Log</button></a>
            <a href="home.php"><button>Logout</button></a>
            <a href="delete_account.php"><button>Delete an Account</button></a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <form action="items.php" method="post">
                <div>
                    <input type="submit" name="add_stocks" value="Add Stocks" onclick="return confirm('Add new stock. Apply?')" />
                </div>
                <table border="1">
                    <?php
                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM items";
                        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                    ?>
                            <tr>
                                <th>ID</th>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Prize</th>
                                <th>Stock</th>
                                <th>Add Stocks</th>
                                <th>Action</th>
                            </tr>
                    <?php
                            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                                echo "<tr>";
                                    echo "<td>" . $row['item_id'] . "</td>";
                                    echo "<td>" . $row['item_name'] . "</td>";
                                    echo "<td>" . $row['prize'] . "</td>";
                                    echo "<td>" . $row['stock'] . "</td>";
                                    echo "<td><input type='text' name='amount_add[]' /></td>";
                                    echo "<td><button type='submit' name='item_delete[]' value='" . $row['item_id'] . "' onclick='return confirm(\"You are about to delete < " . $row['item_name'] . " >. Are you sure?\")' />Delete</button></td>";
                                echo "</tr>";
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            echo "<tr>";
                                echo "<td>No item existed...</td>";
                            echo "</tr>";
                        }
                    ?>
                </table>
            </form>
            <form action="items.php" method="post" id="item_table">
                <label>Item Name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="item_name" placeholder="Name" required="required" />
                <label>Item Prize</label>
                <input type="text" name="prize" placeholder="Prize" required="required" />
                <label>Stock</label>
                <input type="text" name="stock" />
                <input type="submit" name="add_new" value="Add New Item" onclick="return confirm('Add new item. Apply?')" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
<?php
    }
    else {
        header("Location: home.php");
        exit();
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

The 2 codes above works in PHP posting the < tagname name=" *name[ ]* >

---

Now the real code: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLU3k.png) (the Total Prize didn't display, why? Sorry, I'm not really good at javascript)

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if (isset($_SESSION['login_user'])) {
        include("dbconn.php");
        /*{
            code here
        }*/
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Order</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Restaurant Management Information System</h1>
        <h3>Choose an amount of items to stock for order...</h3>
        <div>
            <a href="items.php"><button>Add New Item</button></a>
            <a href="log.php"><button>View Activity Log</button></a>
            <a href="home.php"><button>Logout</button></a>
            <a href="delete_account.php"><button>Delete an Account</button></a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <form action="order.php" method="post">
                <table border="1">
                <div>
                    <input type="submit" name="order_items" value="Order" onclick="return confirm('Confirm order?')" />
                </div>
                    <?php
                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM items";
                        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

                        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                    ?>
                            <tr>
                                <th>ID</th>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Prize</th>
                                <th>Stock</th>
                                <th>Order Qty</th>
                                <th>Total Prize</th>
                            </tr>
                    <?php
                            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                                echo "<tr>";
                                    echo "<td>" . $row['item_id'] . "</td>";
                                    echo "<td>" . $row['item_name'] . "</td>";
                                    echo "<td>" . $row['prize'] . "<input type='hidden' name='prize[]' value='" . $row['prize'] . "' /></td>";
                                    echo "<td>" . $row['stock'] . "</td>";
                                    echo "<td><input type='text' name='quantity[]' onchange='total_prize()' value='0' /></td>"; //not working!
                                    echo "<td><input type='text' name='total[]' readonly /></td>";
                                echo "</tr>";
                            }
                        }
                        else
                            echo "No item to display...";
                    ?>
                </table>
            </form>
        <script>
            int x = 0; //initialize var only once

            function total_prize() { //this function will be call many times
                document.getElementByName("total")[x].value = document.getElementByName("prize")[x].value * document.getElementByName("quantity")[x].value;
                x++;
            }
        </script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
<?php
    }
    else {
        header("Location: home.php");
        exit();
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Just focus on:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['item_id'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['item_name'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['prize'] . "<input type='hidden' name='prize[]' value='" . $row['prize'] . "' /></td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['stock'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td><input type='text' name='quantity[]' onchange='total_prize()' value='0' /></td>"; //not working!
        echo "<td><input type='text' name='total[]' readonly /></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
```

...

```
<script>
    int x = 0; //initialize var only once

    function total_prize() { //this function will be call many times
        document.getElementByName("total")[x].value = document.getElementByName("prize")[x].value * document.getElementByName("quantity")[x].value;
        x++;
    }
</script>
```

Thank you!

Comment: `int x = 0;`? Javascript is not strongly typed. Besides that, the function `getElementByName` is not `Elements` for a reason. It expects name to be unique, and thus only return 1 element.

Comment: @Sumurai8 There's no `getElementByName`, only [document.getElementsByName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName), and name is ok to be not unique, I believe you mean `id` and [document.getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById).

Comment: uhh; sorry, you are right. I am still sleepy I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, whenever a `quantity[]` is changed, it'll update only 1 item, means when you change the value on 4th `quantity[]`(which is `quantity[3]`), it still get `prize[0]` and `quantity[0]`'s value, and then put the compute result to `total[0]`, and if you now want to change that, you will end up change the value to `total[1]` and so on...

The problem is that you only want to change nth elements that you're currently playing with, but a static number `x` can't help you with that, as it only able to ref to 1 index, and it changes when function calls, it won't have a desired behavior.

Solution:

1. Give some index information to your `total_prize` function, like give it the current index.

```js
function total_prize(index) {
  var prize = document.getElementsByName('prize[]').item(index);
  var quanity = document.getElementsByName('quanity[]').item(index);
  var total = document.getElementsByName('total[]').item(index);
  // If any of the dom element not exist, do nothing.
  if (prize === null || quanity === null || total === null) {
    return;
  }
  
  total.value = strToNumber(prize.value) * strToNumber(quanity.value);
}

function strToNumber(str) {
  var num = parseInt(str, 10);
  return isNaN(num) ? 0 : num; 
}
```

```html
<input type="hidden" name="prize[]" value="1"/>
<input type="hidden" name="prize[]" value="2"/>
<input type="hidden" name="prize[]" value="3"/>
<input type="hidden" name="prize[]" value="4"/>

Q1<input type="text" name="quanity[]" onchange="total_prize(0)"/><br/>
Q2<input type="text" name="quanity[]" onchange="total_prize(1)"/><br/>
Q3<input type="text" name="quanity[]" onchange="total_prize(2)"/><br/>
Q4<input type="text" name="quanity[]" onchange="total_prize(3)"/><br/>

T1<input type="text" name="total[]" /><br/>
T2<input type="text" name="total[]" /><br/>
T3<input type="text" name="total[]" /><br/>
T4<input type="text" name="total[]" /><br/>
```

2. Or use the same function without any given info, but loop through all elements and update all of their value each time the function is called.

```js
function total_prize() {
  var prizes = document.getElementsByName('prize[]');
  var quanities = document.getElementsByName('quanity[]');
  var totals = document.getElementsByName('total[]');
  
  // Use the length that is shortest.
  var length = Math.min(prizes.length, quanities.length, totals.length);
  var index, price, quanity;
  for (index = 0; index < length; index += 1) {
    if (quanities[index].value.length === 0) {
      totals[index].value = '';
    } else {
      price = strToNumber(prizes[index].value);
      quanity = strToNumber(quanities[index].value);
      totals[index].value = price * quanity;
    }
  }
  
}

function strToNumber(str) {
  var num = parseInt(str, 10);
  return isNaN(num) ? 0 : num; 
}
```

```html
<input type="hidden" name="prize[]" value="1"/>
<input type="hidden" name="prize[]" value="2"/>
<input type="hidden" name="prize[]" value="3"/>
<input type="hidden" name="prize[]" value="4"/>

Q1<input type="text" name="quanity[]" onchange="total_prize()"/><br/>
Q2<input type="text" name="quanity[]" onchange="total_prize()"/><br/>
Q3<input type="text" name="quanity[]" onchange="total_prize()"/><br/>
Q4<input type="text" name="quanity[]" onchange="total_prize()"/><br/>

T1<input type="text" name="total[]" /><br/>
T2<input type="text" name="total[]" /><br/>
T3<input type="text" name="total[]" /><br/>
T4<input type="text" name="total[]" /><br/>
```